# Acquiring mutex based on given priority on Windows

Tags: windows, ipc

I have several processes which need to communicate, and I want to be able to let only one talk to another at the same time, for example, if I have processes A, B, C, D. If B wants to send a message to A, C cannot send a message, not even to D.

I already have the necessaries pipes for the communication, and I was looking for an object in the WinAPI to implement the exclusivity behaviour.

I'd also need to set a priority, so let's say C is sending a message to D and both A and B want to trasmit, when C is done I need to be able to assure A will always go first.

I know, this sounds like a situation which will lead to starvation, and in fact it will, but I am trying to simulate a real set up which suffer from starvation (CANbus).

Any idea what kind of object I could use?

Comment: The purpose is not really to simulate starvation, but to simulate several processors communicating over CAN using several processes communicating over pipes. In the simulation. I lack the exclusivity of the communication.

Comment: @AlexF while surely simpler, I would prefer to look for a solution which does not involve an external process.

Comment: Exclusivity is easy to come by, just takes a named mutex.  Priority, no, not at all.  It is very common to need a dedicated arbiter process in such a scenario, primarily to make the entire system resilient to unexpected failure.  Which you don't care about in a simulation, but in your CANbus simulation it plays the role of the bus.  Make it all a lot easier by using threads instead of processes.

Comment: @HansPassant would an arbiter process simplify things? How would it behave? I would prefer not needing one but if no other (simple enough) solution exist, adding another process is doable.

Comment: It is not a simplification, it is a requirement.  Only an arbiter can order messages to impose a priority, it acts as the "switchboard".

Answer (score -1):

Windows, like all other modern OSes, will schedule threads according to priority. If you have threads of different priority, and they're all waiting for the same mutex semaphore, the highest priority thread will be run when that mutex is next available.

So you should be able to set your thread priorities such that A is higher up than B, and have a single mutex semaphore that they all acquire before communicating, and release once they've finished. So when C has finished communicating with D it will release the mutex, and of the two ready threads (A and B) Windows will schedule A ahead of B. As A will be taking the semaphore, B will become not ready until A has finished and has released the mutex.

Comment: This is surely something I have taken into consideration, but I have also heard that priorities are not rules but suggestions to the scheduler ( it might not respect the priority set to avoid starving ), and I need something which is deterministic. Also, changing priorities might affect the rest of the execution, which should be done as if it was completely independent.

Comment: @bracco23 No, they're rules. Certainly at points where the kernel scheduler has to make a decision - e.g. where two threads are waiting on the same semaphore, and it's just been released by another - that's where it would have to pay attention to the two threads' priorities. If it didn't, then the thread priority would be being ignored by the scheduler, and what would be the point of that. Thread and process priority works differently in Windows in comparison to the simple scheme used by the *nixes, but it's scheduling behaviour is deterministic.

Comment: @bracco23, I suspect whoever is downvoting my answer hasn't actually bothered to read Chapter 5 of Windows Internals, which sets out the rules. Windows does muck around with process priorities, but the relative priorities of unscheduled threads within a process remain unaffacted by this. Other than dynamically altering process priority according to whether or not it has mouse focus, Windows's scheduler is a priority driven preemptive system just like anything else. What it won't do (and nor will Linux) is resolve priority inversions - but that's not a problem you're enquiring after